# Can you create a batch file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file

Can you write code to create multiple batch files in asp.net? Can you create it and also have the code write batch file commands into the batch files? What I want to do is create .bat files in a certain location on the computer (or make it create a folder to put the .bat files into) on a button click and have it write all the commands into the .bat file. For example, I have a web form the user inputs data, pushes a button and based off the .bat files it creates, it creates a new batch file every time the button is clicked. Is this possible?

Comment: So you're asking whether it's possible to write a plain text file in C#? Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, but it could  have a lot of security consequences, so, be careful.

You create a file using methods in the File class, like File.CreateText.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible but in general, you will only be able to create these files inside your application's folder.

If you need to create the files outside your application's folder, you need to make sure that the App Pool your app runs under, has permissions to write to that folder.

Since batch files are basically executables, I'd be very careful about using them and I would never, under any circumstance take free user input to be placed into those files. You may give the user a set of predefined "commands" to chose from to mitigate your exposure, for example.

Comment: Thank you, How do I make sure the app pool has permissions to write to the folder created?